# How to start kafka server programmatically

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

we are trying to start the kafka server (zookeeper and broker) programmatically in our application. Any api / library available for the same?

Comment: That's generally not a good idea within an actual deployment. Zookeeper should have a minimum of 3 servers on different hosts

Comment: can we connect/start zookeeper and kafka programmatically and thus make a cluster of two more nodes/hosts

Comment: I'm not aware of a feature that allows you to cluster the embedded server. You definitely should use dedicated hardware for each server

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use embedded Kafka, which will run zookeeper and kafka server for you. It is generally used for testing kafka producer/consumer where there is no need to explicitly run them.
For more detail [refer](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka)

To run it, we write `EmbeddedKafka.start()` at the start and  `EmbeddedKafka.stop()` at the end.

Comment: is It possible to start the same programmatically for the production deployement. is it a good idea to create a kafka cluster programmaically and use the same.

Comment: No, EmbeddedKafka is used only for testing purpose. I doubt it will be good idea to use it in production. You can put a question on stack. Others might answer it.